Prove if T is linear map from $V$ to $W$, $s_{n}||v|| \leq ||Tv||$ for every $ v \in V$, where $s_{n}$ is the smallest singular value of T
From Linear Algebra Done Right 7E Singular Value Decomposition Exercise 14.
The exercises asks to prove that if T is linear map from $V$ to $W$, $s_{n}||v|| \leq ||Tv||$ for every $ v \in V$, where $s_{n}$ is the smallest singular value of T.
My current approach:
I write $Tv$ as its SVD, and obtain that
$||Tv||^{2} \geq s_{n}^{2}(|\langle v,e_{1} \rangle|^{2}+...+|\langle v,e_{n} \rangle|^{2}) $
Since $span(e_{1},..,e_{n}) = (nullT)^{\perp}$, I tried to decompose $v$ into $u+r$, where $u \in (nullT)^{\perp}$ and $r \in nullT$, and conclude that $s_{n}^{2}(|\langle v,e_{1} \rangle|^{2}+...+|\langle v,e_{n} \rangle|^{2}) = s_{n}^{2}||u||^{2}$
But then I am stuck, since $||v||^{2} \geq ||u||^{2}$, so my approach doesn't seem to work. What am I missing? Or is there other simpler way?

You seem to be assuming $s_n$ is the smallest positive singular value of $T$, but the question doesn't make this positivity assumption. That is, $s_n$ could be zero.

@angryavian You are right. I will edit my post to reflect that. Fortunately that is a trivial case.

But when $s_n > 0$, then the nullspace of $T$ is trivial, so you are done.

@angryavian Oh right! Thank you, I get it now. So I was just one step away.

(Thanks @angryavian for the hints)
When $s_{n} = 0$, $s_{n}||v|| \leq ||Tv|| $ for all $v \in V$ and we are done.
When $s_{n} > 0$, we take the SVD of T, i.e., for all $v \in V$, $$Tv = s_{1}\langle v,e_{1} \rangle f_{1}+ ... +s_{n}\langle v,e_{n} \rangle f_{n}$$,where $e_{1},...,e_{n}$ is an orthonormal list in $V$, $f_{1},...,f_{n}$ is an orthonormal list in $W$, and $s_{1},...,s_{n}$ are the singular values of $T$ listed in decreasing order.
$e_{1},...,e_{n}$ is also an orthonormal basis of $V$. We thus see that for all $v \in V$, $$||Tv||^{2} = s_{1}^{2}|\langle v,e_{1} \rangle|^{2}+...+s_{n}^2|\langle v,e_{n} \rangle|^{2}\geq s_{n}^{2}(|\langle v,e_{1} \rangle|^{2}+...+|\langle v,e_{n} \rangle|^{2}) = s_{n}^{2}||v||^{2}$$ and we are done.
